# How to Import PGSQL roles into Amazon RDS?

Tags: database, postgresql, amazon-web-services, postgresql-9.3, rds

I am trying to migrate data from a stand-alone PostgreSQL set-up into AWS RDS. I have dumps of all the databases ready to be imported but I need their associated roles first.

What is the correct way to dump all the roles only from the stand-alone instance then import them into RDS?

Comment: Do a `pg_dumpall --globals-only`